# Dropdown button with json in flutter

Tags: json, flutter

I want to read json and use it for items in dropdown button in flutter.
the class of read json from server is:

```
class LoginApi {
  static String token;
static Future<List<dynamic>> pes() async {
    final response = await get(
      '${URLS.BASE_URL}pistachio',
      headers: {HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: "Bearer ${token}"},
    );
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      Map<String, dynamic> map1 = json.decode(response.body);
            return map1['result']['values'];
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

json is :

```
{
    "result": {
        "message": "Ok",
        "status": true,
        "values": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "type a",
                "pistachioCode": "16"
            }
        ]
    },
    "statusCode": 200,
    "message": "Ok"
}
```

and use the json in another class like DropDownButton() function :

```
class Enter extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context)

  {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: DropDownButton() ,
    );
  }
}
```

What do i do?

Answer (score 0):

convert your data like below:

```
class LoginApi {
  static String token;
static Future<List<String>> pes() async {
    final response = await get(
      '${URLS.BASE_URL}pistachio',
      headers: {HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: "Bearer ${token}"},
    );
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      Map<String, dynamic> map1 = json.decode(response.body);
      Map<String, dynamic> valuesMap = map1['result']['values'];
      List<String> values= [];
      valuesMap.forEach((key, value) {
       if (key == 'name') {
         values.add('$value')
       }
    });
            return values;
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

The DropDownButton items: property takes a List.  All you have to do is map out each value to a DropDownMenuItem.

```
FutureBuilder<List<String>> (
  future: Login.pes(),
builder: (context, snapshot) {
  if (snapshot.data != null) {
    return DropDownButton<String>(
      items: snapshot.data.map((value) => DropDownMenuItem(
        value: value,
        child: Text(value),
      ),).toList(),
    );
  }
},),
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but i want to use json for items in dropdown button.

Comment: Still the same code.  DropDownButton has an items: property that takes a List<DropDownMenuItem>.

Comment: please explain more.

Comment: I've updated my answer with how DropDownButton works.

Comment: again thanks but you didn't use json in the code i want items in dropdown button read from json (LoginAPi.pes()).

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood what exactly what you wanted.  There are multiple ways of pushing data to a UI.  I showed updated my answer using a FutureBuiler.

Comment: i use your code but there is an error:
type 'MappedListIterable<dynamic, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<DropdownMenuItem<String>>'

Comment: Forgot to add toList() to the end of the map function. I updated the answer.

Comment: Sorry but there is new error:
type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String'

Comment: The return type of the above method is List<Map<String, dynamic>>.  I've edited the method to convert the data to a List<String>.  If you need the data in a different format later on, you will need to setup a different method to do the conversion and return your original method back to what it was.

Comment: now snapshot.data return [{id: 1, name: type a, code: 16}] and i want to use the name in dropdown button. what do i do ?

Comment: valuesMap.forEach((key, value) {
     if (key == 'name') {
     values.add('$value'));
     }
     }

Comment: My friend, if possible edit code because i bit confused.

Comment: thank you but there is a new error:
The method 'map' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: map(Closure: (dynamic) => DropdownMenuItem<dynamic>)

Comment: what is the data coming out of snapshot.data?

Comment: snapshot.data return null.

Comment: when return values in LoginApi then snapshot.data = null but return map1['result']['values'] then snapshot.data = not null